# How to gitignore all .md files

Tags: git, gitignore

When I go to upload project, or update it on github, from git, I want to hide specific file type, all files of that kind of file, such as notes, .md files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the rule to .gitignore

```
*.md
```

Answer (score 0):

add `*.md` in `.gitignore` file, this will tell git to ignore all files that's end with `.md` extension

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule to .gitignore (optional)

```
*.md
```

And delete them from the repository, if you added them earlier.

```
git rm --cached -- *.md
git commit
```

The notes will remain in the working directory, but they will not be in the repository.